# fluent-ffmpeg resize video to instagram story 9:16

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to resize / upscale any given video to 1080 x 1920 [9:16 aspect ratio]

```
ffmpeg('video.mp4')
.complexFilter([
    `scale=-1:1920,crop='min(1080,1*ih)':'min(iw/1,ih)`,
])
.output('render.mp4').run()
```

I have this piece of code which works and crops the video if the width is greater than the height, but if i have a 4k vertical video 2160x3840, then obviously it doesn't work,
i can just do `scale=iw/2:ih/2` but how can i sniff the initial video resolution and setup different clauses? is there a way i can tackle this in one line?

Comment: Do you want to keep the orientation? As in 16:9 video to come out 16:9 and 9:16 video to come out 9:16?

Comment: In any case, FFmpeg filters accept expressions and you can look up supported functions on [this Documentation Page](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)

Comment: I want to lose the orientation. So 16:9 should be scaled up and cropped in to appear as 9:16. Thanks for the documentation link

Comment: @kesh bro, could you help me with something? [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/di6yFZ62) I'm trying to overlay a video onto a frame/image, i have the overlay working but the video isn't playing. thanks bro